Accidentally hitting other strings while downstroking
I just learned to strum and I use my thumb for upstrokes and the other four fingers for downstrokes (similar to this YouTube video). I don't have a problem with upstroking with my thumb. However, when I try to downstroke from the fifth string to the first string with my four fingers, I accidentally hit all the strings (I usually notice my mistake when I see vibration in the sixth string). The same thing happens when I try to downstroke from string 4 to string 1, I accidentally hit the upper strings with my fingers.
I'm wondering how I can solve this problem and downstroke accurately when playing chords like C, Am, Fmaj7.

The answer is simple, spend time practicing and playing. Learning to strum only the high 4 or 5 strings is a useful acquired skill to have as a guitarist. Over time your strumming will get more accurate and you won’t hear the strings you are trying to avoid. The other post suggests learning to play chords that use more or all the strings but some of these chords sound muddy because of the interval between the two lowest strings, a perfect 4th.
If you really can’t tell if you are strumming too many strings there is an easy way to be able to hear if you do. If you are playing for example an Am chord using 5 strings and want to avoid the low E string, tune the low E a semitone lower to a D# and practice strumming the chord. That will make the chord sound noticeably bad when you strum all 6 strings. If you are playing a 4 string chord like a D, detune the A and E strings in a similar fashion so you can tell when you are hitting extra strings.
This is by no means part of a regular practice routine and I don’t suggest spending a lot of time on it. I only suggest it to help you easily hear if you are strumming too many strings, since your goal is to be accurate in the number of strings you want to strum.
You can practice chord progressions using only 4 string chords like D to Dm, 5 string chords like A to Am and eventually start combining them, say with a blues in A, A A A A D D A A E D A A.
Strumming doesn’t have to be super precise. An individual strum is not that important in the overall scheme of things. If you occasionally hit an extra string or one string less it will not have a big effect on the overall song. Just do the best you can, improve gradually and have fun.

'Accurately'? There are some sites (and teachers) that decree that thou shoudst only play root position chords. Never understood why. There's absolutely no need for each and every chord to be played as such, in fact, it's often good to use inversions.
I understand that there's a problem when there's a bad note that is almost unavoidable somewhere in the 6 strings - it happens all the time with extended chords that occur later in some guitarists' careers.. Guitarists use techniques to obviate this. One simple one is to mute the offending string with something on the fretting hand, usually a fingertip.
That way, with some careful fingering, it's quite possible to strum all 6 strings, as the muted ones won't even be heard!
I was going to write this as a comment, especially the 1st paragraph, as I feel strongly that being encouraged to play exclusively root position chords limits any beginner guitarists.
EDIT: you could also consider, when strumming the top 5 strings, resting your thumb on the 6th. But that means it's not in an optimum position for the next upstrum. So why use thumb at all? And - you tagged classical guitar. Is that appropriate? I'd have thought acoustic would be amore accurate tag.

Thank you. I think even the sound is not very different when I downstroke all the strings for example for Am and C chords

It may depend on which voicing of the C you use. I prefer 2nd inversion, where the fat string is pressed on fret 3. There are several open voicings of that chord. My idea is really for where there's a note which really doesn't belong - like open bottom  (fat) E on an F or F maj7 chord.

This does not answer the question. Regardless of being able to sometimes play chords with more notes and more strings and different inversions, strumming a partial, limited number of strings is an important and necessary skill.

@JohnBelzaguy - hence the mention of muting in the answer.

Muting is not always an option, especially with open chords.

@JohnBelzaguy - so are we discussing several consecutive strings, or what? It's still possible to mute strings when using open chords, in fact, beginners do it all the time..!

That is the implication of the OP, yes. It is possible in some instances but not possible in others. How  do you mute the low A and E strings on an open D chord ?

@JohnBelzaguy - that's only one example! Most are mutable. I would even play the open A on a D chord (2nd position, and some would put thumb over onto 2nd fret bottom string (1st pos.)  But I play with a plec, so it's never really been a problem for me. That apart, I rarely play open chords - no control - but that doesn't help answer, or OP. Actually, just tried it on acoustic, and it's easy. Leave index finger free (use mid, ring and/or pinky) to mute the offending E and A strings! QED!

Yes, there's definitely scope for using first- and second-inversion chords instead of root-position ones.  But that should be an artistic choice based on the musical effect you want, not a practical one based on limited technique.  (This answer doesn't seem to distinguish.)  The lowest note has a very significant impact on the tonality.  (Especially if it's a non-chord tone, such as G/F — though that's a more advanced topic!)
